# virtual box issues and concerns - configure to use hdd rather than ssd?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, ssd, arch-linux

I decided to give arch a go, first in a virtual machine. I had an issue with only getting 32 bit options but I checked my uefi bios and fixed that. I have installed virtual box on an ssd but I want to configure it to use hdd space for the virtual machine. I can not seem to find out how to achieve this... please advise.

When making a virtual machine with virtualbox, I have to set up a virtual disk. I want this virtual disk to use my hdd rather than my ssd, which I believe it is defaulting to.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Please be specific when you revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean that you want to store the virtual hard drives on another drive as to save space in your ssd.  There are two ways to make this happen:

1. Move your .vdi to the larger drive and then from virtual machine settings go to "Storage" and then "Controller:SATA".  At the far right there is a small blue icon and from there choose "Choose a virtual hard disk"
2. Go to file => preferences and set "Default machine folder" to a folder in your larger hard drive.